# ImageView from path

Tags: android

I know this topic already exist, but none of the examples work at my project.

I try to display a image to an ImageView by his real path. What do I wrong?

I tried over MediaScannerConnection and bitmap.

by MediaScanner:

```all
String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/Park-2.jpg";

MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { path }, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                uriImage = uri;
            }});
iv.setImageURI(uriImage);
```

by bitmap:

```all
iv=findViewById(R.id.imageView);

String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/Park-2.jpg";
File imgFile = new  File(path);

if(imgFile.exists()){
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    iv.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
}
```

permissions:

```all
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

code to get path:

```all
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you are using android 7 or above you need to use fileprovider. Also from android 6 and above you need to use dynamic permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add bitmap factory option in your code like below:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("your_path", BitmapFactory.Options())
imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

make sure user allow the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not read nowhere that I need programmaly user permission from API level 23... I got a user permission request in my programm and that works! Thanks!

Comment: most welcome.please vote up for this answer so other user can use this

Answer (score 1):

Try getting your path with Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
Also you can try to use http://square.github.io/picasso/ it really makes what you are doing a lot easier. Example:
Picasso.get().load(new File(...)).into(imageView);